# Não consigo restaurar banco de dados no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

estou tentando restaurar um DBS que tenho em minha maquina, mas infelizmente estou tendo problemas...

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u root -h localhost -p reg_users < /home/ubuntu/workspace/restore.sql' at line 1
```

este é o erro que está retornando, por favor me ajudem

Minha DBS(Restore.SQL)...

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Tempo de geração: 05/05/2017 às 18:41
-- Versão do servidor: 5.7.17
-- Versão do PHP: 5.6.30

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Banco de dados: `reg_users`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura para tabela `user_civ`
--

CREATE TABLE `user_civ` (
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `edereco` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `userCivCod` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura para tabela `user_ong`
--

CREATE TABLE `user_ong` (
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `nome_ong` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `userOngCod` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Índices de tabelas apagadas
--

--
-- Índices de tabela `user_civ`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_civ`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userCivCod`);

--
-- Índices de tabela `user_ong`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_ong`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userOngCod`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabelas apagadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabela `user_civ`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_civ`
  MODIFY `userCivCod` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabela `user_ong`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_ong`
  MODIFY `userOngCod` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Cara, o erro já fala, 'erro de sintaxe', eu sugiro que você poste o que você acha que está acontecendo(código) aqui.

Comment: o que mais posso postar? minha DBS? que código? se refere ao comando usado? se for ja está no post, mas vou comentar aqui tbm "mysql -u root -h localhost -p reg_users < /home/ubuntu/workspace/restore.sq"

Comment: Posta o `Restore.SQL`, pois executei o comando no meu mysql e funcionou

Comment: Esse comando que você comentou aí em cima precisa ser rodado via linha de comando. É isso que você está fazendo? Pela mensagem de erro, parece que você está tentando rodar ele como se fosse uma query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não esta selecionando qual Banco de Dados vai receber seu arquivo SQL. Tenta realizar o Seguinte passo:

1. `mysql -u root -h localhost -preg_users`

Após Logar:

2. `create database reg_users;`
3. `Use reg_users;`
4. `source /home/ubuntu/workspace/restore.sql;`

Se observar, o seu arquivo SQL não vem especificando a linha `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS reg_users;`

Esta linha serve para criar o Banco caso ele não exista.